# using rems with a pixel fallback

Tags: css

I'm working on mobile first framework. The project has a broad range of requirements, with a mass of browsers and devices over various locations to cater for.
One of my key locations to target is India, where the browser and device usage trends differ greatly to that in the UK or US.

India browser usage
http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-browser-IN-monthly-201301-201312-bar

UK Browser usage
http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-browser-GB-monthly-201301-201312-bar

The browsers that I need to target for india region are opera, android, uc browser and nokia, but each of those have their little quirks. With that the range of devices differ

Opera mini - does not support rems
Android (prior to chrome)  v2-v4 has problems with both rems and ems
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/mobile.html

-- Am I right in assuming that more recent versions of Android come pre installed with Chrome and the OS web browser?

I'd ideally like to use rems, as it removes the issues of nested content inheriting the em scale of its parent element. However based on the research on http://www.quirksmode.org, I need to have a fall back set.

So I'm going to need to declare a px value.

For example, can I do this:

```
h1 {font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.846rem; line-height: 2.308rem; margin-bottom: 0.769rem} /* 24px / 30px / 10px */
```

Or do I have to do something like this?

```
h1 {font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px}
h1 {font-size: 1.846rem; line-height: 2.308rem; margin-bottom: 0.769rem} /* 24px / 30px / 10px */
```

Or is there something else that is better?

I have seen a few js poly-fills, such as https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill, but there maybe cases where JavaScript is not enabled so this won't work.

Additionally I am try to focus on performance, so I want to keep the number of requests to a minimum and the keep the css a clean as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your style declarations will work fine. CSS renders code in a cascading fashion, this means if one value is declared after another, the latter will be used. If a browser can render `px` but cannot render `rem`, the `rem` values will simply be ignored. If a browser can render both `px` and `rem`, the latter of the two will be used:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 12px; /* 1. Font size set to 12px */
    font-size: 1rem; /* 2. Font size set to 1rem, overriding previous value */
}
```

In this example, `rem` will be used on browsers which support that unit, and `px` will be used on those which do not.

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 1rem; /* 1. Font size set to 1rem */
    font-size: 12px; /* 2. Font size set to 12px, overriding previous value */
}
```

In this example, `px` will be used on both browsers which support `rem` and browsers which do not.

[Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem) will give you a better overview of which browsers support this unit.

---

As for performance, each character contained within a CSS file equates to 1 byte. The more bytes contained within your stylesheet, the longer it will take a browser to download it. So of course, adding `px` values alongside `rem` values will ultimately add to the download time, but most of the time this is negligible.

---

As for whether Android devices come bundled with Chrome: no, this is not the case. This is entirely up to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

Either style declaration will work for you - if a browser doesn't support `rem`s it will fall back to the pixel value.

This is one of those situations where I set the `html` font-size to 62.5% to take the base font-size down to 10px. This makes the calculations very straight forward and is easy to spot errors in your type declarations.

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```