# benefits of unitless line height instead of rem line-height

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at switching my `line-height` set up from `rem` based to unitless.

I'm trying to understand why I should do this what the benefits are compered to staying with rems, such as, is there a performance/rendering benefit, or does unitless help with responsive?

The main benefit for me at the moment is reduction in required `px` fallback declarations.
I am using `rem` values with `px` fallbacks as the support between `rem` and `em` units is about on par.

Also resetting the `em` value back to 1 for nested elements, is a headache. I feel it's just as much work as declaring a`em`reset for nested elements as it is for a `px` fallback.

Additionally older versions of ie, ignore the `rem` property/value and fallback to the `px` property/value.

This is how I was declaring my `font-size` and `line-height` for text elements.

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem; /* 16px */
    line-height: 25px;
    line-height: 2.5rem; /* 25px */
}
```

Currently, my body `font-size` and `line-height` are:

```
html {
   font-size: 62.5%; /* reset font-size to 10px */
}

body {
    font-size: 1.6rem; /* 16px */
    line-height: 2.5rem; /* 25px */
}
```

What benefit is there is switching to this?

```
html {
   font-size: 62.5%; /* reset fon- size to 10px */
}

body {
    font-size: 1.6rem; /* 16px */
    line-height: 1.66667; /* 2.5rem / 25px*/
}
```

If I have a `h1` set like this

```
h1 {
    font-size: 3.0rem; /* 30px */
    line-height: 3.6rem; /* 36px */
}
```

I still need to declare a `line-height` other wise the inherited value becomes a bit crazy

```
h1 { 
    font-size: 3.0rem; /* 30px */
   /* line-height: 50px; (inherited from body line-height (1.66667)  */
}
```

So I declare a `line-height` that is acceptable

```
h1 {
    font-size: 3.0rem; /* 30px */
    line-height: 1.2; /* 3.6rem / 36px */
}
```

Great! but if I still need to declare a `line-height`, what is the benefit of switching to unitless?

Also, when I'm using `line-height` to vertically align some text in an container, should I use unitless, stick with `rem` as it's a specific height.

```
.my-container { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 4.0rem;
}
```

I'm assuming that the rule of thumb is to assign unitless height just to text objects like `p`, `h1`, `h2` etc.

Here is a codepen demonstrating the unitless implementation
http://codepen.io/onebitrocket/pen/qLzlc

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be expecting that the basic font size is alwatys 16px. It is unclear what you expect to gain then by using percentages or `rem` units, instead of simply setting everything in pixels. Thus, it is impossible to compare the pros and cons, since we don’t know your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're worried about what I can only assume to be line-height it is allowed to do a unit-less line-height period. Essentially the calculated height will base off of the calculated font-size.

```
div{
   font-size: 1.6rem;
   line-height: 4; // should be the exact same as 4.0rem;
}
```

Personally I do not like to use rems as you are seeing they really need many fall backs and known calculation. Not all developers use a standard for rems since it hasn't been accepted as the standard. If it did then maybe it would be better to use as it can help for responsiveness, but with media queries you shouldn't have to worry about how responsive your site is.

I am someone who pushes for px. Just a preferred method that works very well. EMs and REMs give me a headache as they do not work perfectly in every case. I can predict pixels without worrying about someone changing one value and breaking everything else.

Just a thought.

Comment: I disagree. I find rems removes the headache of ems calculations, having to reset the ems value of each child can be such a pain, and add just as much bloat, and maybe more to the css. Additionally, the support is pretty much comparable. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/mobile.html  For mobile, and on desktop only early ie versions don't support rem, and they just omit the declaration and use the fallback. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21854416/1376820

Comment: I agree they remove the headache of the em, but I do not feel they are that much more helpful. As I said it is just a personal preference of use and seeing how complicated a site can become when using these forms of measurement. Then having the client tell you that it is not working in a specific browser because one reads ems/rems in a different manner.