# Unitize mixin generates css code for px and rem

Tags: less, shopware

I am currently learning to develop theme in shopware and trying to use it's built-in library of less mixins and variables.

But when I used .unitize mixin to convert px value to rem, after inspecting css I figured out that it generates css for px and then override it with corresponding rem value.

As you can see in attached image, for container class max-width is defined in px and then again in rem.

Why it is generating those values 2 times?

[image]

Comment: There's no reason for it to be doing that. I assume it's simply an oversight or error made by the developers of Shopware.

Comment: Yes,in mixin definition also, value is for both.

Comment: There ***is*** [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21854535/2712740).

Comment: Thanks.Probably the smallest accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is no bug, its just a fallback.